# WCF response as Json in ASP.NET WebForms, using Json.NET

Tags: javascript, wcf, json.net, webforms

I'm using a WCF Service in which I would like to respond with a list of objects. As my objects are generated by entity framework, I can't really return a List as it has some circular references and default serialization fails. Thus, I'm using anonymous types to create a list of objects containing only the properties I need.
This is what I'm doing, using Json.NET:

```
[OperationContract]
        public string DoWork()
        {
            using (X ent = new X())
            {
                var modules = from p in ent.Modules select new { Name = p.Name, Value = p.ID };
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modules);
            } 
        }
```

Now this is my javascript which renders the result inside a table:

```
function btn_onclick() {
            var srv = new DDSProjectManagement.ProjectsService();
            srv.DoWork(Res, null, null);
        }
        function Res(dataList) {
            var divObj = document.getElementById('tablePos');

            var name = 'Name';
            var desc = 'Description';

            var tableStart = '<table><tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>';
            var tableContent = '';
            var tableEnd = '</tbody></table>';

            for (var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
                tableContent += '<tr><td>' + dataList[i].Name + '</td><td>' + dataList[i].Value + '</td></tr>';
            }
            divObj.innerHTML = tableStart + tableContent + tableEnd;
        }
```

If I do this, the parameter javascript gets is just a string and it is not able to see it as a list of my objects. Of course, it should be a Json string and I could try to parse it such that it extracts the objects from it. But I really want to use the javascript as it is now and modify the service. For example, changing my service in the following will work just fine:

```
public List<SimpleObject> DoWork()
        {                
            return new List<SimpleObject>() { new SimpleObject("Florin", 1), new SimpleObject("Andrei", 2) };
        }
```

SimpleObject is not an EntityFramework object so this has no problem. I suppose the default serializer is a Json one and javascript should get basically the same parameter: a Json string.

So my question is how do i make my method send a list of anonymous type objects to my JS as building the string via Json.NET didn't work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to send a string and then parse the JSON from JavaScript. There's simply no other way to do it. (Well you could serialize in a different format I guess, like XML, but it'd be essentially the same problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked for me. The return type of the method is Stream and here is how it works:

```
    public Stream GetModules()
            {
                using (PMEntity ent = new PMEntity())
                {                
                    List<Module> ret = new List<Module>();
                    ret = ent.Modules.Include("Project").ToList();

                    return new MemoryStream(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                            ret.Select(e => new { Name = e.Name, Value = e.ID }))));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) ... It will let you push information to your JavaScript from your server side. I do something similar where I have a WCF service on my ASP.NET MVC3 page and then whenever my service receives data I just push it to my JavaScript.

My service sending info to my SignalR 'mediator':

```
public void Message(string messagePacket)
    {
        new NotificationMediator().NotifyClients(messagePacket);
    }
```

In my case I just new up a new mediator (SignalR Hub) and then call a method on it. Here is my SignalR handler for this (NotifyClients):

```
public void NotifyClients(string message)
    {
        Hub.GetClients<NotificationMediator>().Log(message);

    }
```

Now that Log is a JavaScript method on my UI. Here is my JavaScript code to handle this:

```
mediator.Log = function (message) {
        var msg = $.parseJSON(message);
        $("#logContainer").append(msg.Data + "<br />");
```